# Pebble iOS, There was an error trying to install provided app

Tags: ios, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm trying to develop an application for the pebble that connects to an iOS device.

You don't need to read the stuff below. **Long story short, I keep getting "There was an error trying to install provided app" whenever I try to load a pebble app I made onto my phone. Why is this?**

### Things I've tried so far

I have an iPhone 6 which connects to my pebble well, and I can load and run apps. I also plugged in my phone to the computer and ran Xcode so I could enable developer mode in the phone itself, and enabled Developer Mode in the pebble app, then Enabled Developer Connections. I am logged in with my same pebble account that I develop things with on cloudpebble.

I tried sending an app to my pebble via cloudpebble, and it worked on the emulator, but when I sent it to my pebble my phone said "There was an error trying to install provided app".

I updated to the most recent iOS and pebble OS. It said "There was an error trying to install provided app".

I tried compiling a c++ project instead. I tried changing the SDK to version 2. I tried running cloudpebble on Safari and Firefox. I tried downloading the pbw file, sending it onto my phone using dropbox, and then running it there.

I went and installed the pebble developer kit on my Mac, and built a project that successfully compiles via pebble install --phone 123.4____ but my phone says "There was an error trying to install provided app".

I was able to compile an app that runs the pebble SDK with swift, and it builds successfully and tries to connect, but isn't able to make any connections.

I uninstalled the pebble app and reinstalled it. I forgot the bluetooth connections, reset my pebble to factory defaults, then reconnected it to my phone.I tried restarting my phone. I made sure to have the pebble app open and on the My Pebble screen before trying to load an app onto it.

None of the above worked.

What am I doing wrong? My phone clearly knows that someone is sending it an app, it's just barfing for some reason and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was - for some reason, the old pebble app no longer functions for developers. I installed the pebble time app and then things worked well.